# How To Merge Vidoes Side by Side Using Ffmpeg Having Length More Than 2 Mins

Tags: java, android, merge, video-processing

i want to merge two mp4 videos having length of 2mins and I am using FFMPEG commands to  merge videos it take too much processing time is there any other way or commands to speed up am also using `-preset ultrafast` but it's not working.

here i am using this command

```
ffmpegcommand = new String[]{"-y", "-i", recordedvideo, "-i", file.toString(),
                    "-filter_complex",
                    "[0:v:0]pad=iw*2:ih[bg];" +
                            "[bg][1:v:0]overlay=w;" +
                            "[1:a]volume=0.9[A];[0:a]aecho=1:0.1:" + Constant.DELAY + ":" + Constant.DECAY + "[B];[B]volume=70[C];[C][A]amix=inputs=2[a]",
                    "-map", "[a]",
                    "-c:v", "libx264", "-shortest", "-preset",
                    "ultrafast", path + time + ".mp4"};
```

Answer (score 1):

*I've written this code because once in a while I want to quickly concatenate multiple videos without having to worry about each size and format.*

**Concatenation of files with same and different codecs/formats/sizes/aspect ratios.**

(Make sure every video has audio! (Add silent audio if necessary) )

```
    # set video size of the output
targetWidth=1024
targetHeight=576

#this scaler preserves the aspect ratio of the input video and adds padding if needed.
#a video with a size of 720x576 will be upscaled to 1350x1080 to preserve the aspect ratio and padded left and right to achieve 1920x1080.
smartScale="scale=iw*min($targetWidth/iw\,$targetHeight/ih):ih*min($targetWidth/iw\,$targetHeight/ih), pad=$targetWidth:$targetHeight:($targetWidth-iw*min($targetWidth/iw\,$targetHeight/ih))/2:($targetHeight-ih*min($targetWidth/iw\,$targetHeight/ih))/2:color=black, setdar=ratio=16/9, setfield=tff"

# inputs are scaled to the same size and given a label
# then they are concatenated
ffmpeg \
-i "01 video 1280x720.mov" \
-i "02 video 720x576.mkv" \
-i "03 video 1920x1080.mp4" \
-filter_complex "\
[0:v]${smartScale}[scaled_v0]; \
[1:v]${smartScale}[scaled_v1]; \
[2:v]${smartScale}[scaled_v2]; \
[scaled_v0][0:a][scaled_v1][1:a][scaled_v2][2:a]\
concat=n=3:v=1:a=1[v][a]" \
-map "[v]" -map "[a]" -c:v libx264 -crf 23 -c:a aac concatenated.mkv
```

I've tested it multiple times and it works nicely.

Comment: @darke7 how much processing time does it take i have videos of 2 mins and it almost takes 2 mins to merge what about you ?

Comment: @Muhammed Haroon I've concatenated two ~ 15 Minute videos (1920x1080, AVC). It was processed with 2.6x speed , about 12 minutes.

Comment: @darke same is my case it take too much time i have 2 mins videos and it take almost 1 to 2 mins to merge side by side i just want to merge them within 12 to 20 seconds as smule app is doing in smule app it take seconds to merge

Comment: @Muhammed Haroon do you need to concat "video2" AFTER "video1"?
Or do you need "video1" on the LEFT and "video2" on the RIGHT side?

Comment: @darke yes i want two videos side by side one on left and other on right

Answer (score 0):

What is the output of your command ?

Do you have an error message related to ffmpeg ?

Comment: no just it take too much time anything to reduce processing time?